# validation rule conditional upon value of myVariable

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, jquery-validate

Usung jquery validator, I would like to apply a rule (regex) only if a certain variable (myVariable) has a given value.

I thought about...

```
rules: {
    NHI:{regex:function() {
            var myVariable =6;
            return myVariable =6;}    
    },
},
```

I thought if the expression myVariable=6 evaluates to true then the validation rule will be applied. And if the expression is false then it won't be applied.
What I noticed is that sometimes this approach seems to work, other times it doesn't as if the expression is only sometimes being evaluated. Sometimes changing the code to use === instead of = seems to force a fresh evaluation of the expression. Sometimes not.

Ultimately I want to run the validation only for certain user IP addresses but firstly want to understand a simple way to turn validation on or off with javascript.

The following however works:

```
var myVariable =6;
...
rules: {
NHI:{regex:myVariable ===6}    
},
```

so perhaps it as simple as that?

Closer to my goal:

```
var countryCode ="NZ";
...
rules: {
NHI:{regex:countryCode ="NZ"}    
},
```

This turns validation on (if NZ) and off otherwise. Great. So I then insert the geoPlugin to the head:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"  ></script>
```

and change my code to

```
var countryCode=geoplugin_countryCode();
...
rules: {
NHI:{regex:countryCode ="NZ"}    
},
```

However it seems to evaluate to false now even though country is NZ

Comment: If what you want is to finally have `regex` member true when `myVariable` value is 6 and false otherwise, your function must merely contain `return myVariable == 6;`.

Comment: Properly implement the `depends` property or use `.addMethod()` to write your own rule.